# Proving there is a constant $C$ such that $f=g+C$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Consider the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, If $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

I have to prove the following corollary:

> **Corollary:** If $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then there exists a constant $C$ such that $f=g+C$.

**My attempt:** Consider the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. We have that $h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. By the lemma we have that $h$ is constant on $[a,b]$. In other words, $h(x)=C$, where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant. Then, $C=f(x)-g(x)$ in $[a,b]$. We conclude that $C+g(x)=f(x)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: yes$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: It looks fine to me.